# An strange python "if" syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, if-statement, python-3.2

I get this error: Invaild syntax in my "if" statement and rly can't figur why, can anyone of you guys help me? I'm using python 3.2
here is the part of my code whit the error my code:

```
L = list()
LT = list()
tn = 0
players = 0
newplayer = 0
newplayerip = ""
gt = "start"
demsg = "start"
time = 1
status = 0
day = 1
conclient = 1
print("DONE! The UDP Server is now started and Waiting for client's on port 5000")
while 1:
    try:
        data, address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
        if not data: break
        ################### reciving data! ###################
        UPData = pickle.loads(data)
        status = UPData[0][[0][0]
        if status > 998: ##### it is here the error are given####
            try:
                e = len(L)
                ori11 = UPData[0][1][0]
                ori12 = UPData[0][1][1]
                ori13 = UPData[0][1][2]
                ori14 = UPData[0][1][3]
                ori21 = UPData[0][1][4]
                ori22 = UPData[0][1][5]
                ori23 = UPData[0][1][6]
                ori24 = UPData[0][1][7]
                ori31 = UPData[0][2][0]
                ori32 = UPData[0][2][1]
                ori33 = UPData[0][2][2]
                ori34 = UPData[0][2][3]
                ori41 = UPData[0][2][4]
                ori42 = UPData[0][2][5]
                ori43 = UPData[0][2][6]
                ori44 = UPData[0][2][7]
                ori51 = UPData[0][3][0]
                ori52 = UPData[0][3][1]
                ori53 = UPData[0][3][2]
                ori54 = UPData[0][3][3]
                ori61 = UPData[0][3][4]
                ori62 = UPData[0][3][5]
                ori63 = UPData[0][3][6]
                ori64 = UPData[0][3][7]
                ori71 = UPData[0][4][0]
                ori72 = UPData[0][4][1]
                ori73 = UPData[0][4][2]
                ori74 = UPData[0][4][3]
                ori81 = UPData[0][4][4]
                ori82 = UPData[0][4][5]
                ori83 = UPData[0][4][6]
                ori84 = UPData[0][4][7]
                ori91 = UPData[0][5][0]
                ori92 = UPData[0][5][1]
                ori93 = UPData[0][5][2]
                ori94 = UPData[0][5][3]
                ori101 = UPData[0][5][4]
                ori102 = UPData[0][5][5]
                ori103 = UPData[0][5][6]
                ori104 = UPData[0][5][7]
                npcp11 = UPData[0][6][0]
                npcp12 = UPData[0][6][1]
                npcp13 = UPData[0][6][2]
                npcp21 = UPData[0][6][3]
                npcp22 = UPData[0][6][4]
                npcp23 = UPData[0][6][5]
                npcp31 = UPData[0][6][6]
                npcp32 = UPData[0][6][7]
                npcp33 = UPData[0][7][0]
                npcp41 = UPData[0][7][1]
                npcp42 = UPData[0][7][2]
                npcp43 = UPData[0][7][3]
                npcp51 = UPData[0][7][4]
                npcp52 = UPData[0][7][5]
                npcp53 = UPData[0][7][6]
                npcp61 = UPData[0][7][7]
                npcp62 = UPData[0][8][0]
                npcp63 = UPData[0][8][1]
                npcp71 = UPData[0][8][2]
                npcp72 = UPData[0][8][3]
                npcp73 = UPData[0][8][4]
                npcp81 = UPData[0][8][5]
                npcp82 = UPData[0][8][6]
                npcp83 = UPData[0][8][7]
                npcp91 = UPData[1][0][0]
                npcp92 = UPData[1][0][1]
                npcp93 = UPData[1][0][2]
                npcp101 = UPData[1][0][3]
                npcp102 = UPData[1][0][4]
                npcp103 = UPData[1][0][5]
                d0 = (status, )
                d1 = (ori11,ori12,ori13,ori14,ori21,ori22,ori23,ori24)
                d2 = (ori31,ori32,ori33,ori34,ori41,ori42,ori43,ori44)
                d3 = (ori51,ori52,ori53,ori54,ori61,ori62,ori63,ori64)
                d4 = (ori71,ori72,ori73,ori74,ori81,ori82,ori83,ori84)
                d5 = (ori91,ori92,ori93,ori94,ori101,ori102,ori103,ori104)
                d6 = (npcp11,npcp21,npcp31,npcp21,npcp22,npcp23,npcp31,npcp32)
                d7 = (npcp33,npcp41,npcp42,npcp43,npcp51,npcp52,npcp53,npcp61)
                d8 = (npcp62,npcp63,npcp71,npcp72,npcp72,npcp81,npcp82,npcp83)
                d9 = (npcp91,npcp92,npcp93,npcp101,npcp102,npcp103)
                pack1 = (d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8)
                pack2 = (d9, )
                dat = pickle.dumps((pack1,pack2))
                while tn < e:
                    server_socket.sendto(dat, (L[tn],3560))
                    tn = tn + 1
            except:
                pass
                print("could not send data to some one or could not run the server at all") 
        else:
```

the part where the console tells me my error is is here:

```
if status > 998:
```

Comment: Check the line above the `if` statement, and count the number of brackets.

Comment: There has *got* to be a way of condensing that data into something shorter and more readable. [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).

Comment: maybe s/he *really* likes typing

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
status = UPData[0][[0][0]
```

The second opened bracket `[` is not closed. The Python compiler keeps looking for the closing bracket, finds `if` on the next line and gets confused because `if` is not supposed to be inside brackets.

You may want to remove this bracket, or close it, according to your specific needs (the structure of `UPData`)